# How to add properly Data REST dependency in Spring Boot Maven project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I try to add Spring Data REST dependency using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding this dependency I catch an exception - `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry;`

And the Action suggestion: `Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry`

I tried to add this dependency to fix the problem:

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

But it didn't help me.
How could I fix this problem?

I use Spring Boot version - 2.2.7.RELEASE, Maven version - 3.3.9

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml

Comment: It is big file with 1000 lines generated by Jhipster...@SimonMartinelli

Comment: I assume that there are version conflicts

Comment: First if you use version 2.2.7.RELEASE as mentioned in your post but the pom snippet shows a different version as @SimonMartinelli already mentioned it could be a version conflict... you should use only a single version ...

Comment: @khmarbaise there is no same version for this dependency... 2.0.0 is latest

Comment: Artifact of spring-boot-starter-data-rest is loaded based on the spring-boot-starter-parent version so, either you update the spring boot parent version or exclude the spring core plugin.